# NFT metadata update

Tags: nft

and I hope you are doing well.

I'm developing a project which involves NFT for cars to keep the records immutable and permanent. I was wondering if metadata can be updated. Let's say that I created an NFT of my car last year, and it was registered 10,000 km by then. Today, I want to interact with the same smart contract and register the present mileage, which is 15,000 km. is that possible?

Thank you and have a great day

Lisandro

Comment: Hello Ismael, thank you for your comment. I saw that answer before placing the question. According to the one you are referring, I should be able to update the mileage. So, move from 10,000 to 15,000, but what we need is to keep the information immutable, so both records should be there like this:

2020May15 —> 10,000 (NFT creation)
2021Apr25 —> 15,000 (New mileage record)

Comment: @Lisandro What you are asking for is basic logic. It is not related to ethereum itself but algorithm.

Comment: Let me add that from your comment, I storngly think you do not understand the basics of transactions in a blockchain.

Comment: @Lisandro The metadata is off-chain so it is mutable. You could extend an ERC 721 token to add on-chain properties to keep track of mileage, it is allowed within the standard.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain We're all here learning new things. Don't take an issue too personal, try to be nice and help others that are learning.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain you are right, maybe I got confused with some concepts. I'm not an expert and as Ismael mentioned before, I'm learning.
Thank you to both of you for your comments, and I wish you a great weekend!